# How to make content non visible outside UIView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, contentmode

I have an `UIImageView` with `UIViewContentModeCenter`, so Images that it holds are not getting scaled or deformed. But this way if the image is larger, it can be seen outside the ImageView's frame.
I don't want to crop the image (user can scale it, so the loss of data is not an option), but I need to make the part  of it outside of `ImageView` invisible or something

Comment: you can set clipsToBounds property of the UIImageView to YES, this will make sure that your image will remain inside the frame, If you don't want to do this, then need to look for other option?

Comment: I've settled to go with `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` . Thanks for the solution though, it does part of the work I aimed for

Comment: something is left in this question?

Comment: so posted the solution as answer for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to put UIImageView inside UIScrollView and then manage size and position things inside scrollView.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set clipsToBounds property of the UIImageView to YES.

Comment: Thanx. Clipping to bounds help a bit, but what I trully needed was UIImage in UIScrollView